I need some assistance finding out what it causing and Event Log Auditing event
I am using Alienvault to log our SIEM Events from our servers, and I am trying to find out how to debug what is causing this recurring Auditing Event in our Windows Event Logs.
I have found out that SentinelOne is scanning this file at the time, but is there a way to see what change caused this event to be raised? I seems to occur about every 5 minutes.
Here is a sample event being logged. (Please note i have removed any company information)
AV - Alert - "1726685231" --> RID: "18113"; RL: "8"; RG: "windows,policy_changed,"; RC: "Windows Audit Policy changed."; USER: "<ComputerName>$ "; SRCIP:

"None"; HOSTNAME: "() ComputerIPAddress->WinEvtLog"; LOCATION: "() ComputerIPAddress->WinEvtLog"; EVENT: "[INIT]2024 Sep 18 13:47:14 WinEvtLog:
Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(4719): Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing: (no user): no domain: .Company.local: System audit policy was changed.
Subject:  Security ID:  S-1-5-18  Account Name:  $  Account Domain:  Company  Logon ID:  0x3e7  Audit Policy Change:  Category:  %%8274
Subcategory:  %%12806  Subcategory GUID: {0cce9222-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030}  Changes:  %%8449[END]";
Any help would be appreciated.

0cce9222-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030 is the Application Generated audit subcategory. "This subcategory audits applications that generate events by using the Windows Auditing application programming interfaces (APIs). Applications designed to use the Windows Auditing API use this subcategory to log auditing events related to their function." The Changes: %%8449 is the audit subcategory was successfully added/enabled. I believe this category was used by Authorization Manager. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc726036(v=ws.11)

Thanks for the information. I Should have added that all the servers are 2019, is Authorization Manager still in use on these?

I would open this event in the Windows event viewer so that you can actually interpret it properly. I'm pretty surprised that AlienVault isn't capable of formatting this event correctly - makes it pretty useless.
